# ERD - Recursive relationship with two primary keys

Tags: sql, recursion, attributes, entity, erd

I have a product table:

**Product (ID, Version)**

And I am having trouble creating a recursive table named "Update".
this table should have a product ID and for each product, there will be an old version and a new version.

this is my desired outcome:

**Update (ProductID, OldVersion, NewVersion)**

but unfortunately, if I have two primary keys the result would be:

**Update (NewProductID, NewVersion, OldProductID, OldVersion)**

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Hi. I hope you don't mind a comment re [this recent deleted question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66300363/3404097). I would like to help you if you'd still like, and I am interested in how your post got to its form & whether my comments helped. An answer or even each of a sequence of answers per the parts of the post is probably simple and/or a duplicate, but right now it's not clear what the question(s) would be. (Difficulty arises from sets vs bags & from null=null vs not, not from full join per se.) That's why I commented there, what context & question did you begin with? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In UPDATE you need to make the PK the ProductID and either the OldVersion or NewVersion. The other version ID is then an attribute of this table. It doesn't matter which Version ID you choose to be part of the PK (from a technical perspective, it may make a difference from a usability/business perspective) but you need to be consistent, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

This relationship should not be recursive, it is a normal relationship. My proposed solution should be like:

Product (ProductID, name, etc..) // ProductID is the primary key

Update (ProductID, Version) // both are the primary key